# Download and Save tar.gz file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, tar

I use a wifi module which does not allow to use the request library to make requests, but I have my own library to make HTTP requests and it works very well.

I would like to download a file.ta.gz from a server and save it to a folder, with my library I receive the file as a byte array, but I don't know how to reconstruct it from that:
[image]

some specifics details aboout how i configure the server to send data :

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary
nContent-Length: 3579

Can please heplp to save this file ? the contente is on variable ! Thanks.

Jayen,

Comment: [Built-in tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, if you've already gotten the file into memory inside of a variable, then you also might be interested in [StringIO/BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o).

Comment: Thanks for reply !  I try this =>     f = open("data.tar.gz", "rb")
   f = io.BytesIO(data_byte) !!!!!!  but nothing happen, i thinks i'm using wrong this library

Comment: If what you're writing is what you're working with, then you already have the `tar.gz`-file downloaded. If that's the case, then you don't have to use `BytesIO` any more. That was just if you've already read the file. Just try to open the file with `tarfile.open("data.tar.gz", "r:gz")`

Comment: finnaly a can download my file :) ! thanks, it's just more complicated to download big file ...